# Subtraction between signed and unsigned followed by division

Tags: c++, unsigned, integer-overflow, arithmetic-expressions

The following results make me really confused:

```
int i1 = 20-80u;    // -60
int i2 = 20-80;     // -60
int i3 =(20-80u)/2; // 2147483618
int i4 =(20-80)/2;  // -30
int i5 =i1/2;       // -30
```

1. `i3` seems to be computed as `(20u-80u)/2`, instead of `(20-80u)/2`
2. supposedly `i3` is the same as `i5`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IIRC, an arithmetic operation between signed and unsigned int will produce an unsigned result.

Thus, `20 - 80u` produces the unsigned result equivalent to `-60`: if `unsigned int` is a 32-bit type, that result is 4294967236.

Incidentally, assigning that to `i1` produces an *implementation-defined* result because the number is too large to fit. Getting `-60` is typical, but not guaranteed.

Comment: _Incidentally, assigning that value to i1 is undefined behavior_ Are you sure about that? I taught that conversion from unsigned int to signed int is well defined for all values of unsigned int.

Comment: There is no signed integer overflow here. There are conversions. See [conv.integral](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral).

Comment: @rozina: Huh, I had never before seen that conversion works differently in this respect. Fixed

Answer (score 10):

> ```
> int i1 = 20-80u;    // -60
> ```

**This has subtle demons!** The operands are different, so a conversion is necessary. Both operands are converted to a common type (an `unsigned int`, in this case). The result, which will be a large `unsigned int` value (60 less than `UINT_MAX + 1` if my calculations are correct) will be converted to an `int` before it's stored in `i1`. Since that value is out of range of `int`, the result will be implementation defined, might be a trap representation and thus might cause undefined behaviour when you attempt to use it. However, in your case it coincidentally converts to `-60`.

---

> ```
> int i3 =(20-80u)/2; // 2147483618
> ```

Continuing on from the first example, my guess was that the result of `20-80u` would be 60 less than `UINT_MAX + 1`. If `UINT_MAX` is 4294967295 (a common value for `UINT_MAX`), that would mean `20-80u` is `4294967236`... and `4294967236 / 2` is 2147483618.

---

As for `i2` and the others, there should be no surprises. They follow conventional mathematical calculations with no conversions, truncations, overflows or other implementation-defined behaviour what-so-ever.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, converting -1 to unsigned is well defined and it is UINT_MAX. But if you then convert UINT_MAX back to int it is suddenly implementation defined? And could not be -1?

Comment: Nice answer day :)

Answer (score 3):

The binary arithmetic operators will perform the [usual arithmetic conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions) on their operands to bring them to a common type.

In the case of `i1`, `i3` and `i5` the common type will be *unsigned int* and so the result will also be *unsigned int*. Unsigned numbers will wrap via modulo arithmetic and so subtracting a slightly larger unsigned value will result in a number close to unsigned int max which can not be represented by an int.

So in the case of `i1` we end up with an implementation defined conversion since the value can not be represented. In the case of `i3` dividing by `2` brings the unsigned value back into the range of int and so we end up with a large signed int value after conversion.

The relevant sections form the C++ draft standard are as follows. Section `5.7` *[expr.add]*:

> The additive operators + and - group left-to-right. The usual arithmetic conversions are performed for
>   operands of arithmetic or enumeration type.

The usual arithmetic conversions are covered in section `5` and it says:

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield
>   result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result.
>   This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions, which are defined as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> - Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater than or equal to the
>     rank of the type of the other operand, the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to
>     the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.

and for the conversion from a value that can not be represented for a signed type, section `4.7` *[conv.integral]*:

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and
>   bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

and for unsigned integers obeys modulo arithmetic section `3.9.1` *[basic.fundamental]*:

> Unsigned integers shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2n where n is the number of bits in the value
>   representation of that particular size of integer.48

Comment: @Hurkyl: Damned, I am sleeping standing today, I mangled the unsigned overflow and conversion from unsigned to signed (the latter being implementation defined). I'll self-destruct my comment...